# Apache 403 Error

Tags: apache, http-status-code-403

I can access certain links from my site with no issue. However, if I try and manually type in the same URL as the link/button I get a 403 error.

FOr instance http://www.sumobid.com/logout.php

I have verfied the permissions on the file but am still getting the error.

This is on a dedicated server.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you got any .htaccess file there? If so, what's its content?

Comment: Sounds like it's checking the `Referer` (sic) header.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're not logged in for the second case. I.e., you can't logout if you're not logged in.

Edit: I.e., it seems as if the app is throwing a 403 for pages that require auth but don't have it. (As opposed to, say, redirecting to the login page.)

Comment: Seems I fixed my own problem. It turns out that I had inadvertently turned on LinkProtection in cPanel. Once that was disabled everything started working as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Seems I fixed my own problem. It turns out that I had inadvertently turned on LinkProtection in cPanel. Once that was disabled everything started working as it should